# Use declaration merging to build a type (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have used [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) as follows

```
function barfoo(): void { /* magic */ }
namespace barfoo {
    export let maz: Array<string> = [];
}
```

But the question is, how can I use this. For example, if I use it as follows

```
function doIt(cb: barfoo): void {
    cb.maz = [10];
    cb();
}
```

typescript is complaining: `Cannot find name 'barfoo'.`

[DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20barfoo()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20alert(barfoo.maz%5B0%5D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Anamespace%20barfoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20let%20maz%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doIt(cb%3A%20barfoo)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20cb.maz.push(10)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20cb()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AdoIt(barfoo)%3B)

Any suggestions how to fix the type (without using `any` :) ?

UPDATE: I figured out how to create new functions of this type

```
let x: { (): Array<string>; maz: Array<string>; };

x = (() => {
    var _x : any = function () { };
    _x.maz = [];
    return _x;
})();

let y: { (): void; maz: Array<string> } = (() => {
    let _y: any = function fake(): Array<string> {
        return ((cb: any): Array<string> => {
            return cb.maz;
        })(fake);
    }
    _y.maz = [];
    return _y;
})();
```

[DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20x%3A%20%7B%20()%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%3B%20maz%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ax%20%3D%20(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20_x%20%3A%20any%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_x.maz%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20_x%3B%0D%0A%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20y%3A%20%7B%20()%3A%20void%3B%20maz%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%20%7D%20%3D%20(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_y%3A%20any%20%3D%20function%20fake()%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20((cb%3A%20any)%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20cb.maz%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)(fake)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_y.maz%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20_y%3B%0D%0A%7D)()%3B)

But, as you can see, the second example is very complex. Is this the correct way or can this be simplified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `barfoo` is a *value*, but in your definition of `doIt()` you are mistakenly treating it as a *type*.  All values *have* a type, but the name of a value is rarely the name of its type.  If I do `let x = 3;` then `x` is a value, but its type is `number`, not `x`.

It seems from your code you want to be able to pass in the value `barfoo` to the function.  (Why you would want to do such a thing is your business, but if you're only ever going to pass that one value into the function, you might want to consider not having it be a parameter at all.  Up to you, though.)  So the `cb` parameter should be declared to be the type of `barfoo`, whatever it is.  By inspection you can see it is something like `{ (): void; maz: string[] }`. 
 But luckily TypeScript allows you to quickly get the type of a named value by using a [type query](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/31/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript#typescripts-type-queries), which reuses the keyword `typeof`.  The type of `barfoo` is simply `typeof barfoo`:

```
function doIt(cb: typeof barfoo): void {
    cb.maz = [10];  // error, hey 10 is not a string
    cb();
}
```

This works, and even catches another bug for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

---

### UPDATE

If you want to make more objects of the same type as `barfoo`, that is: a callable function (of no arguments and returning `void`) which also has a `maz` property containing an array of strings, the most straightforward way to do it is to use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which merges all properties into the first argument and returns it as the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of all the argument types.  Like this:

```
const barfoo2 = Object.assign(
  function() {
    // function body here
  },
  {maz: ["some","stuff"]}
);

doIt(barfoo2); // works
```

Good luck again!

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! And,  I have my reasons for doing something like this :)

Comment: I've tried to create new functions of this type (checkout my updated questions). But I noticed that this is not straighforward. Especially my second example. Is this how it is done, or can it be simplified?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.